# JMS Queue Resource Leak Suspected - injecting Connection, Session, and Queue

Tags: java, spring, jms

I am trying to identify where a suspected memory / resource leak is occurring with regards to a JMS Queue I have built.  I am new to JMS queues, so I have used many of the standard JMS class objects to ensure stability. But somewhere in my code or configuration I am doing something wrong, and my queue is filling up or resources are slowing down, perhaps inherent to unknown deficiencies within the architecture I am attempting to implement.

When load testing my API (using [**Gatling**](https://gatling.io/)), I can run 20 messages a second through (which is a tiny load) for most of a ten minute duration.  But after that, the messages seem to back up, and the ability to process them slows to a crawl.  Generally time-out errors begin to occur once the overall requests exceed 60 seconds to complete.  There is more business logic that processes data and persists it to a relational database, but none of that appears to be an issue.

Interestingly, subsequent test runs continue with the poor performance, indicating that whatever resource is leaking is transcending the tests.  A restart of the application clears out whatever has become bloated leaking.  Then the tests run fast again, for the first seven or eight minutes... upon which the cycle repeats itself.  Only a restart of the App clears the issue.  Since the issue doesn't self-correct itself, even after waiting for a period of time, something has filled up resources.

When pulling the JMS calls from the logic, I am able to process ***hundreds of messages*** a second.  And I can run back-to-back tests runs without leaking or filling up the queue.

Although this is a Spring project, I am **not** using Spring's `JMS Template`, so I wrote my own Connection object, which I injected as a Spring Bean and implemented as a single connection to avoid creating a new connection for every JMS message I sent through.

Likewise, I configured my `JMS Session` to *also* be an injected Bean, in which I use the Connection Bean.  That way I can persist my Connection and Session objects for sending all of my JMS messages through, which are sent one at a time.  A Qpid Server I am calling receives these messages.  While it is possible I am exceeding it's capacity to consume the messages I am producing, I expect that the resource leak is associated with my code, and not the JMS Server.

**Here are some code snippets to give you an idea of my approach.  Any feedback is appreciated.**

**JmsConfiguration** (key methods)

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
   return new JmsConnectionFactory(user, pass, host);
}

@Bean(name="jmsSession")
public Session jmsConnection() throws JMSException {

   Connection conn = jmsConnectionFactory().createConnection();
   Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

   return session; //Injected as Singleton
}

@Bean(name="jmsQueue")
public Queue jmsQueue() throws JMSException {
    return jmsConnection().createQueue(queue);      
}

//Jackson's objectMapper is heavy enough to warrant injecting and re-using it.
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

**JmsMessageEnqueuer**

```
@Component
public class MessageJmsEnqueuer extends CommonThreadScope {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("Session")
   private Session jmsSession;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("jmsQueue")
   private Queue jmsQueue;

   @Value("${acme.jms.queue}")
   private String jmsQueueName; 

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("jmsObjectMapper")
   private ObjectMapper jmsObjectMapper;

   public void enqueue(String message, String dataType) {

      try {
         String messageAsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
         MessageProducer jmsMessageProducer = jmsSession.createProducer(jmsQueue);

         TextMessage message = jmsSession.createTextMessage(message);
            message.setStringProperty("dataType", dataType.name());

         jmsMessageProducer.send(message); 

         logger.log(Level.INFO, "Message successfully sent.  Queue=" + jmsQueueName + ", Message -> " + message);

      } catch (JMSRuntimeException | JsonProcessingException jmsre) {
           String msg = "JMS Message Processing encountered an error...";
           logService.severe(logger, messagesBuilder() ... msg)
      }

   //Skip the close() method to persist connection...
   //Reconnect logic exists to reset an expired connection from server.
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending persistent or non-persistent messages? What is the broker configuration like? Brokers are usually pretty complex with lots of ways to tune resource usage, performance, etc. Have you tried changing the broker configuration in any way? If so, what did you change and what was the result? Also, you say that when you remove the JMS calls you can process hundreds of messages. What kind of messages are these? I assume they aren't JMS since you removed the JMS logic. Please clarify.

Comment: AFAIK, JMS Session is not thread safe, so it is not a good idea make it singleton bean.

Comment: @JustinBertram : Great questions, and important information to add since the scope of JMS is certainly vast across servers, clients, and implementations.

I am sending persistent messages, so a full handshake is required between the client and broker.  I am using JMS 1.1 (not the simplified 2.0 API), using a Qpid Client to connect to a Qpid Server as the broker.  I am working with the team that configures and maintains the brokers on their Stage and Production servers, and we will test an alternative broker that is not in heavy use by other customers.  I will post the results here.

Comment: @JustinBertram : The "hundreds of messages" are not JMS, as you correctly inferred.  Rather, they are a series of data manipulations of user data (including a relational DB backend), with our JMS messages being only a subset of the logic that is processed.  QA tests perform CRUD transactions on user data.  It is through these load tests that the resource leak / locks was observed.  Without the JMS message production being called, we are able to easily process hundreds of users in this manner every second.  With the JMS calls occurring, we run into issues at just 20 users a second.

Comment: @user1516873 : That is a great point. The docs I read also indicated that JMS Sessions are NOT thread-safe, although the JMS Connection should be. I thought that it wouldn't be an issue since the Session's single-threaded nature shouldn't deadlock, so long as I am not doing transactional processing. Shouldn't multiple threads doing operations block for each other?  But if process threads ARE coliding, that could be my underlying problem. As I run the test suite locally, it certainly appears we have a resource deadlock of some kind! I am rewriting code to only re-use the Connection itself.

Comment: If the JMS messages you're sending aren't being consumed quickly you may be running into producer flow control from the broker. Have you explored this avenue?

Comment: @JustinBertram : Yes, we explored that possibility as well, in case the broker was having difficulty keeping up with our message flow.  We are a high producer customer, with multiple instances of our service, and we will be scaling much higher.  Although we were pleased to see that even with the eight instances of our service producing messages concurrently (each single-threaded), the broker WAS able to keep up with a traffic flow of at least a factor of ten above what we were producing.

Comment: However, there are still concerns that with their single server instance, that they might be struggling with handling messages from the 100+ customers tied into them.  According to their logs and stats, there wasn't an issue.  We have been switched to a new broker, for further testing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my resource leak / deadlock issue simply by rewriting my code to use the simplified API provided with the release of JMS 2.0.  Although I was never able to determine which of the Connection / Session / Queue objects was giving my code grief, using the Context object to build my connection and session was the golden ticket in this case.

Upon switching to the simplified API (since I was already pulling in the JMS 2.0 dependency), the resource leak immediately vanished!  This leads me to believe that the simplified API does more than just make life easier by providing an easier API for the developer to code against.  While that is already an advantage to begin with (even without the few features that the simplified API doesn't support), it is now clear to me that the underlying connection and session objects are being managed by the API, and thus resolved whatever was filling up or deadlocking.

Furthermore, because the resource build-up was no longer occurring, I was able to triple the number of messages I passed through, allowing me to process 60 users a second, instead of 20.  That is a significant increase, and I have fixed the compatibility issues that prevented me from using the simplified JMS API to begin with.

While I would have liked to identify precisely what was fouling up the code, this works as a solution.  Plus, the fact that version 2.0 of JMS was released in April of 2013 would indicate that the simplified API is definitely the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but a [MessageProducer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html) extends `AutoClosable`, suggesting it to be closed after it is no longer of use. Since you're not using a `try-with-resources` or explicitly close it afterwards, the jmsSession may contain more and more producers over time. Although I am not sure whether you should close per method call, or re-use the created producer.

Have you tried using a profiler such as VisualVM to visualize the heap and metaspace? If so, did you find any significant changes over time?

Comment: Now that is a fascinating question!  I looked up the docs on Java's JMS MessageProducer class, and you are certainly correct.  I had missed that, completely, and I definitely am not using the "try-with-resources" statement.  Fairly early on in my troubleshooting, I went back and pulled all of the classes I had auto-wired as injected Spring beans, and left only the JMS Connection as a reusable-bean.  Based on the helpful comments from this community, as well as the JMS 1.1 documentation I read... much of it conflicting unfortunately... The Connection was about the only safe object to inject.

Comment: So to your question, @Michiel, I have NOT used a profiler yet.  However, your suggestion that the JmsSession may contain more and more producers over time is a valid possibility.  Since I was using JMS 2.0 dependency, I switched to the simplified API (also released with JMS 2.0) and tried that first.  Immediately the resource leak vanished, which leads me to believe that the simplified API does more than just make life easier for the developer to code.  It is clear that the underlying connection and session objects are being managed, and thus resolved whatever was filling up or deadlocking.